# PHP: Limit Curl simultaneous threads

Tags: php, curl

How can you limit the simultaneous threads when using Curl with PHP?

Comment: What do you mean by "simultaneous threads"? Can you post an example?

Comment: I mean how many users can use Curl at the same time. I'm accessing an external API via HTTP and am not allowed to have more than 18 simultaneous threads open to access it.

Comment: How are these scripts run? Do you make a curl request on each request sent from the browser, or do you have cron scripts?

Comment: I'm calling them directly from PHP with curl_init and curl_close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing built in that you can use, but you could store a count of how many currently active sessions you have. Once you open a curl session, you increase the count, and when you receive the response and close the session, you decrease the count.

You can store the count in a file, for example. Just open the file, read the count, increase it or decrease it, then save it again in the file.

Answer (score 1):

What I use, is the `shell_exec` function like this :

```
$max_threads = 30;
if(shell_exec('ps -ef | grep "curl" | wc -l') < $max_threads)) {  
    shell_exec('curl http://www.google.com');  
}
```

The if statement will check the number of current working threads on your machine corresponding to "curl".

But this implies that you are going to launch curl via the shell_exec function and not through the PHP API.

Answer (score 1):

You could use curl_multi_* functions that process multiple curl handles simultaneously, setup 18 sessions and execute them in a bunch. Depends on the task.

[read more](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php)

Comment: @Frank Vilea, the `curl_multi_*` functions are great. If you're in a situation in which you can use them, then by all means, go ahead. They are actually the only real multi-threaded operations you can do with PHP that I know of.